# HTTP Response to a GET request has undefined body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, httpresponse

This is my server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var allRoutes = require('./routes/allRoutes.js');
app.use('/', allRoutes.default);

var server = http.createServer(app);
module.exports = server;
server.listen(3000);
```

And this is the code of allRoutes.default:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var morgan = require('morgan');

router.use(morgan('tiny'));

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.status(200).send('hello world');
  console.log(res.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Simplest possible stuff. With one single exception: "console.log(res.body);" logs "undefined". I tried sending JSON data instead of a plain 'hello world', using bodyParser in my router instead of app, processing get requests to '/' in app instead of router and still nothing. I can not get res.body.

Can I actually do anything other than "res.body = 'hello world'" that works? "res.body = 'hello world'" works but I don't think it is the only way to do this.

Comment: Don't you mean req.body?

Comment: No I don't. I send a GET request to my server and I'm trying to assert over res.body. For all I know, there must be some property of response that contains the actual response

Comment: Well body-parser sure ain't relevant then. It processes the request

Comment: Well, I need something to process the response. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: Express documentation don't mention a way to retrieve the body of the response. [Express Response](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res)